# FusedLocationApi MapView in Fragment - addConnectionCallbacks, onConnectionSuspended

Tags: android, google-api-client, fusedlocationproviderapi

I have a `MapView` in a fragment, and I'm having two problems that I can't seem to find solutions for. I've searched but I don't see anyone else having these problems. For reference, I am mainly following [this](http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html) tutorial on the developer pages.

This is my fragment:

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment
        implements GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
                   GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
                   LocationListener
```

The first problem is here:

```
 mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)  //problem!
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this) //problem!
            .build();
```

Calling `addConnectionCallbacks(this)` gives an error saying it cannot be applied to `myPackageName.MapFragment`. I know you have to pass a `GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks` listener here, but every example I see uses `this`, and I'm not sure what to do. The same problem arises in `addOnConnectionFailedListener`. In my fragment I have implemented all necessary methods, such as `onLocationChanged()`.

The second problem is here:

```
@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i)
{
    Log.i(TAG_MAP_FRAGMENT, "GoogleApiClient connection has been suspended");
}
```

This gives an error message saying: `Method does not override method from its superclass`. I've searched and I haven't been able to find anyone else with this problem. I'm not sure how to deal with it.

Anyone know how to fix these? Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of:

```
implements GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
           GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener
```

try:

```
implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
           GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener
```

This resolves all three problems originally posted above. *However*, now the method `onDisconnected()` is marked with an error `method does not override method from superclass`.

The error is fixed when you use all four:

```
implements GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
           GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
           GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
           GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener
```

This doesn't seem ideal, but it works, at least for now. If you stumble across this and you know of a better fix, please leave a reply.